# Oracle database - solaris 10 9/10 where is i can find

Tags: database, oracle, solaris-10

We have Oracle tech login but cannot find the elusive Solaris 10 9-10 SW load iso file.

We have just about everything else for Sol 10 .... and can't restore a an ORACLE DATABASE  backup without it to a client's rebuilt server.

Anyone have an idea where to find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The landing page for older releases is in Knowledgebase entry [Where to download Oracle Solaris ISO images and Update Releases (Doc ID 1277964.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Sun%20Microsystems/1277964_1.html).

Direct links to your release "Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 ISO images):

- [12827080](https://updates.oracle.com/ARULink/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=12827080) - Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 Operating System - x86-64 (64-bit)
- [12827077](https://updates.oracle.com/ARULink/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=12827077) - Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 Operating System - x86-64 (32-bit)
- [12827076](https://updates.oracle.com/ARULink/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=12827076) - Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 Operating System - SPARC (64-bit)
- [12827072](https://updates.oracle.com/ARULink/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=12827072) - Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 Operating System - SPARC (32-bit)

Note that you not only need an Oracle account, but also the appropriate rights for this release.

Comment: tks so much!!!!